# Shared normal map baking problem in different objects

Tags: uv, texture-baking, normal-map

I'm trying to create a "screw panel texture", screw uv's are overlapping of the panel uv as I wanted, I baked combined diffuse+glossy,

[image: baked screw panel]

as can be seen, screws are shown on the top-down right corner of the texture, so far everything is as it should be

when I want to bake normal map, all texture just appears as red 0.5, green 0.5, blue 1.0 or when I change the R G B vectors in the bake section all I get is flat colored screw normals like green or orange,
screw normals are not showing as x,y,z values, I wonder where I'm mistaken, I want to make these panel+screws like this for example:

[image: example bake]

in the example, I know the blue channel is 0

here is the .blend file i'm working on:
[image]

I tried many things in the bake section and shader editor but couldnt accomplish it, my question is how can I do like this? and also is there anything simplier about uv unwrapping, I unwrapped screw uv to the panel uv with "project from view", is there a more practical/efficient/logical way to unwrap overlapped when there were thousands of screws and objects? thanks in advance...

Comment: In a different forum, someone said the solution to the problem, when I join all the screws as an object and check the "selected to active" option in the "bake" section, it works correctly.